# CSM and 4x4 PCF with only 4 samples

Tags: opengl, shadow

I have recently implemented Cascaded shadow mapping(CSM) and everything works just fine without any flickering/shimmering/acne. It's time now to implement a smooth filter and PCF seems to be right candidate, but this filter can be really expensive if we use a 4x4 PCF with 16 samples instead of 4(hardware linear filtering). My question is, how reliable is the hardware version when using Nvidia or AMD/ATI card/drivers? Reading the OpenGL doc: https://www.opengl.org/wiki/Sampler_Object#Comparison_mode

"*When linear filtering is used, the actual returned value is implementation-defined.*"

Is it possible to identify with OpenGL commands if 2x2 PCF filtering with one sample is supported by the hardware? I need to have a fallback if i'm going to use the optimized solution, because otherwise the results can look terrible if this is not supported by the hardware.

From Nvidia: http://http.developer.nvidia.com/GPUGems/gpugems_ch11.html

See **11.4 Using Fewer Samples**.

Comment: What do you mean by "*2x2 PCF filtering with one sample*"?

Comment: Sorry for the late response. See this PDF: http://developer.download.nvidia.com/presentations/2008/GDC/GDC08_SoftShadowMapping.pdf and search for "2x2 PCF in one fetch". It seems that both Amd and Nvidia have implemented this on the current hardware.

Comment: That PDF is just talking about regular old PCF. It's only "in one fetch" in the sense that it's one fragment shader read operation. It's still reading 4 separate samples, even if the hardware is doing it in a single cached memory lookup. And whether it's hardware or software, the results will look the same. Or at least, it will look the same if it's implemented the same way.

Comment: But it should be a little bit faster than manually sampling the texture four times?

Comment: If you're using shadow samplers, then the implementation will be doing whatever the implementation does. You won't be "manually sampling the texture four times".